# wordpress dynamic urls witout redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, url, plugins, wildcard

I need to create dynamic urls all loading same page (please note loading not redirecting) plugins that I could find only do redirects. Basically what I need is:

```
/somepage/something
/somepage/anotherthig
/somepage/thething/morethings
```

all loading existing page

```
/somepage
```

but the original url must be kept (not a redirect). Any advice on how t do it ( a plugin that does this works as well if you know of one) is greatly appreciayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be that hard and can be achieve by modifying `$wp_query` and `$post` global variable,

try this code

```
// modify variable by hooking it on 'wp' action
add_action( 'wp', function() {

    global $wp, $wp_query, $post; //define global variable
    //include $wp variable so you can check the url request

    // list the url you want to use
    $dynamic_url = [
        'somepage/something',
        'somepage/anotherthig',
        'somepage/thething/morethings'
    ];


    // check if page request is found from the array above
    if ( in_array( $wp->request, $dynamic_url ) ) {

        // build query argument
        $args=[
            'post_type' => 'page', //assuming its a page
            'p' =>  26 // page ID of the page you want to display on those dynamic URLS
        ];

        // run the query and assign it to $wp_query global variable
        $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

        // modify is_single wp_query param and tell it its not a post
        $wp_query->is_single = '';

        // modify is_page wp_query param and tell it its a page
        $wp_query->is_page = 1;

        //assign  (1st) found post to global post variable
        $post = $wp_query->posts[0];

        //modify header as 202 status (unless you want these pages to stay as 404), by defualt its a 404
        status_header( 202 );

        //done
    }

});
```

Comment: hi, this is almost what i need, the only change that is needed: instead of in_array check, perform a regex match for 'somepage/*'. In any case this is a good approach, thank you

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this plugin to create dynamic url's. this plugin is free.**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/sdk-wp-dynamic-url/

if you are looking **something advance** then this plugin will surely do for you but its paid:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/if-so/

Hope that Helps

Happy Coding

Comment: Thank you, but these plugins modify the content of a page dynamically, what I need is a way to load the same page for multiple wildcard urls

Comment: check this one: 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213016/access-the-same-page-from-multiple-urls-wildcard
hope it helps

Comment: Hi, I have seen this one, the add_rewrite_rule would work but ror this to be usable for my needs I will need to turn it in to a plugin with UI. I was realy hoping to avoid this but it seems like I do not have much choice. Thnx for your help anywayz.